# Displaying Address Infinitely or Oven no Output at All while Implementing Stack Using Linked List with C Syntax Problem

Tags: c

Can anyone helps me out with this code? So the problem here is that I tried to implement stack using linked list, but every time after I call `pop()` function or `push()` function, and call `display()` function, it will be printing infinitely, or in some other compiler it won't be printing at all.

**The difference with other's questioner's stack linked list is that I don't directly use the `push()` function when creating a stack, but instead I use a `create()` function which helps me creating a stack linked list directly from an array. And also, here I use C syntax instead of C++ syntax like many other questioner.**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct stackLinkedList
{
    int data;
    struct stackLinkedList *next;
} *top=NULL;

void create(int A[],int size)
{
    top=(struct stackLinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(struct stackLinkedList));
    top->data=A[0];
    top->next=NULL;
    struct stackLinkedList *temp=NULL;
    for(int i=1;i<size;i++)
    {
        temp=(struct stackLinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(stackLinkedList));
        temp->data=A[i];
        temp->next=top;
        top=temp;
    }
}

void display(struct stackLinkedList *iterator)      //assign iterator with first node
{
    while(iterator!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ",iterator->data);
        iterator=iterator->next;
    }
}

bool isEmpty(struct stackLinkedList *top)
{
    if(top==NULL) return true;
    else return false;
}

bool isFull()
{
    struct stackLinkedList *temp=(struct stackLinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(stackLinkedList));
    if(temp==NULL) return true;
    else return false;
}

void push(struct stackLinkedList *top,int data)
{
    if(isFull()) 
    {
        printf("cannot push more values, memory is full!");
    }
    else
    {
        struct stackLinkedList *temp=(struct stackLinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(stackLinkedList));
        temp->data=data;
        temp->next=top;
        top=temp;
    }
}

int pop(struct stackLinkedList *top)
{
    struct stackLinkedList *temp=(struct stackLinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(stackLinkedList));
    if(temp==NULL) return NULL;
    else
    {
        int temporary=top->data;
        struct stackLinkedList *temp=top;
        top=top->next;
        free(temp);
        temp=NULL;
        return temporary;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int A[]={1,3,5,7,9};
    create(A,5);
    display(top); printf("\n");
    printf("deleted value is: %d\n",pop(top));
    display(top); printf("\n");                          //the output always goes wrong
    return (0);
}
```

I've asked to my instructor, but he said that the problem was in my machine. But I'm not sure if it is true, since I already tried on DevC++ and GDB online compiler as well

Comment: Your `pop` and `push` functions don't manipulate the global `top` variable, but instead work on their own local variables also named `top` - therefore your `display` function then attempts to derefence a `free`d object, invoking *undefined behavior*

Comment: And you clearly need a better instructor, blaming your machine for such an error is completely unprofessional

Comment: Your `isFull` function allocates some memory and then just discards the pointer without freeing or returning the address of allocated memory. That causes a memory leak. Then in `push` another piece of memory is allocated where you do not check the return value whether it is `NULL`. That approach is broken by design.

Comment: Additionally, your `pop` function also allocates some memory what is not freed. That allocation is completely useless. You do not need more memory. You are supposed to free memory.

Comment: All I knew is that If I take the parameter as pointer then I can manipulate the global top pointer. @UnholySheep

Comment: You're right, I think it is weird to allocate memory in the `pop()` function and then check the `NULL` condition, he said that it is for "exception handling in case when stackunderflow" but I'm not sure if it is gonna works @Gerhardh

Comment: Stack underflow would mean the list does not contain any nodes when you try to remove the first one. You have the `isEmpty` function for that purpose. It is not at all related to allocating new memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually it's your pop() that takes a copy of your top pointer.
In order to manipulate it call it that way with this version or don't fill parameter with you current version :

```
int pop(struct stackLinkedList **top)
{
    struct stackLinkedList *temp=*top;
    {
       int temporary=(*top)->data;
        *top=(*top)->next;
        free(temp);
        temp=NULL;
        return temporary;
    }
}
```

and in your main() :

```
    printf("deleted value is: %d\n",pop(&top));
```

Comment: So technically is it like moving 1 step ahead? I mean, if we want to manipulate a data variable, then I use single pointer. If I want to manipulate a single pointer then I need a double pointer, and so on?

Comment: @Arren whatever you want to modify in a function cannot just be passed to that function but you need to provide the address of it. If that "whatever" is a pointer, you need to pass the address of that pointer.

Comment: @Arren yes exactly when you pass a variable to a function it gets a copy of its value (and this copy has a different address) that is why you can't modify a variable directly nor a pointer itself : " if we want to manipulate a data variable, then I use single pointer. If I want to m..." you guessed right